# "startupinfo) windowserror error 2 the system cannot find the file specified" with tesseract

Tags: python, subprocess, tesseract

I've been trying for hours to fix that problem with `windowserror error2` but it remains even after looking for specific solutions

So here is my program :

```
"from PIL import Image

import pytesseract

img = Image.open('D:/Divers/Projet plaques/m.png')

img.show()

img.load()

i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)"
```

and here is the error message:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Divers\Projet plaques\Recognition.py", line 18, in 
>       i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
>
> File "D:\Divers\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
>       config=config)
>
> File "D:\Divers\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
>       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>
> File "D:\Divers\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File "D:\Divers\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable"

I have no idea how to fix this as the problem seems to be burried deep. 
I have Windows 10, Python 2.7, PIL and tesseract.